# Flutter ColorFiltered Widget - White Balance?

Tags: flutter, blend-mode

I'm trying to apply a White Balance or Auto White Balance to a child widget using ColorFiltered.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ColorFilter-class.html

Just to clarify what I mean by "White Balance":

"White balance (WB) is the process of removing unrealistic color casts, so that objects which appear white in person are rendered white in your photo. Proper camera white balance has to take into account the "color temperature" of a light source, which refers to the relative warmth or coolness of white light."

I was searching into the blend modes here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/BlendMode-class.html but I found nothing about WB or AWB. I'm afraid I might need to develop a custom Matrix to transform the child image.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any news?